# timepicker component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I have developed a simple timepicker component.

The functionality of this component is

a) Show time in both 12 hour format and 24 hour format

b) User can select hour, minutes, am, pm

c) When sending the time to the server, the time should be in 24 hour format

For now the bug I have seen is at the initial load if the time is in PM format, the 24 hour time is not shown

Can anyone look at the code and help me to improve my code and fix that one bug, please?

Below is the code with demo

```
import React from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import "./time.css";

class TimePicker extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.calculateMeridian(props.time);
    this.state = {
      time: this.convertTime(props.time),
      hour: this.calculateHour(props.time),
      hourTime: this.convertTime(props.time),
      selectedNumber: 1,
      meridian: this.calculateMeridian(props.time),
      minutes: this.calculateMinutes(props.time),
      hasError: false
    };
  }

  convertTime = time => {
    const splittedTime = time && time.split(":");
    const hour = splittedTime && splittedTime[0];
    if (hour > 12) {
      // const hour = time.split(':')[0];
      const momentInstance = moment(time, "hhmm");
      const twelveHourTime = momentInstance.format("h:mm");
      console.log("twelveHourTime", twelveHourTime);
      return twelveHourTime;
    }

    return time;
  };

  calculateMinutes = time => {
    const splittedTime = time && time.split(':');
    console.log('minutes', splittedTime);
    return splittedTime[1].split(' ')[0];
  }

  calculateHour = time => {
    const splittedTime = time && time.split(':');
    return splittedTime[0];
  }

  calculateMeridian = time => {
    const splittedTime = time && time.split(':')[1].split(' ');
    console.log('splitted time', splittedTime);
    return splittedTime[1];
  }

  handleClick(time) {
    const { meridian, minutes } = this.state;
    const hourTime = moment(`${time}:${minutes}`, [
      "hhmm A"
    ]).format("h:mm");
    this.setState(
      {
        time,
        hour: time,
        selectedNumber: time,
        hourTime
      },
      () => this.props.onClick(hourTime)
    );
  }

  handleTimeAmPm(meridian) {
    const { time, minutes, hour } = this.state;
    const hourTime = moment(`${hour}:${minutes} ${meridian}`, [
      "h:mm A"
    ]).format("h:mm");
    console.log('hourTime', hourTime);
    this.setState({ meridian, hourTime }, () => this.props.onClick(this.state.hourTime));
  }

  handleMinutes = e => {
    const { value, min, max } = e.target;
    if (value >= min && value < max) {
      const hourTime = moment(
        `${this.state.hour}:${value}}`,
        ["hhmm"]
      ).format("h:mm a");
      if (value.length < 2) {
        this.setState({ minutes: "0" + value.slice(-2), hourTime }, () =>
          this.props.onClick(this.state.hourTime)
        );
      } else {
        this.setState({ minutes: value.slice(-2), hourTime }, () =>
          this.props.onClick(this.state.hourTime)
        );
      }
    } else {
      this.setState({ minutes: "00", hasError: true });
    }
  };

  render() {
    let time = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
      time.push(
        <div
          className={this.state.selectedNumber === i ? "hand selected" : "hand"}
          key={i}
          onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
        >
          {i}
        </div>
      );
    }
    console.log('time', this.state.hourTime);
    return (
      <div className="card card-md" style={{ width: "100%", maxWidth: "100%" }}>
        <div className="time-date">
          <div className="display">
            <div className="content">
              <div className="main-title">
                {this.state.hour}:{this.state.minutes}{this.state.meridian}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="control">
            <div className="slider">
              <div className="time-control">
                <div className="clock">
                  <div className="clock-face">
                    <div className="center" />
                    {time}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="actions">
                  <div className="am" onClick={() => this.handleTimeAmPm("am")}>
                    am
                  </div>
                  <div className="minutes">
                    <div className={this.state.hasError && "input error"}>
                      <input
                        type="number"
                        min={0}
                        max={60}
                        value={this.state.minutes}
                        onChange={this.handleMinutes}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="pm" onClick={() => this.handleTimeAmPm("pm")}>
                    pm
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TimePicker;
```

DEMO

https://codesandbox.io/s/o53r9nr9z5

Answer (score 1):

Just invoke your am/pm handler inside componentDidMount.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.handleTimeAmPm(this.state.meridian);
}
```